# How to convert 2 3-way switches to one single pole switch with dimmer?

Tags: wiring, lighting

In the past I've purchased Kasa's smart switches (HS200). I have two wired right now, and working properly. These were single pole switched that replaced single pole switches. So, pretty straight forward.

I now have a new Kasa single pole smart switch (HS220) with a dimmer. I want to install it in my bedroom, but not sure how to wire it.

The current setup:

1. 4 PHILIPS flood bulbs 39w/120v controlled by 2 switches
2. 2 PHILIPS flood bulbs 39w/120v controlled by another 2 switches

Plus I have a ceiling fan on it's own switch, which I don't think it will matter.

**I would like to end up with only 1 switch that controls all 6 bulbs instead of 4 switches controlling separate sets of bulbs.**

So what will the wiring look like?

I also read that I need to make sure that the new Kasa Switch with Dimmer can handle all bulbs. The Kasa switch is rated 300W for incandescent light bulbs. How can I calculate the necessary wattage? Is it as simple as 6 (bulbs) * 39w?

**UPDATE:**

So after much reading... here's what i've done so far:

On one wall:

1. I removed both switches (won't need them at all).
2. For each switch I connected the hot wire to one of the traveler wires and capped the second traveler wire. I also bought ground wire clips to clip it to the metal box.

I turned the power back on and the remainder 2 switches on the other wall were still functioning properly.

Now I need to convert those 2 remainder switches in to one single pole switch. From what I've read I only need to use one hot wire, but need to pigtail the traveler. I am not 100% sure though. So I took a picture hoping someone can help me out.

On each side there are: 1 hot (black with white tag), 2 travelers (one black one red), set of neutral (white with nut), 1 ground

[image]

Comment: Yes the wattage of the 6 floods will be 6 x 39W = 234W. That would fit within the rating budget of a 300W dimmer and still leave a bit of margin. I would not try to add more bulds or increase wattage on any of the six.

Comment: Do you need lighting control at both *switch locations* involved?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel no. I want all 4 switches (have 2 sets of 2) gone, and replaced with just one switch.

Comment: Do you know which travelers you capped off at the far-end switch box?

Answer (score 1):

After much reading, and much trial and error... mostly error. I ended up using this service -> justanswer.com

They connected me to a electrician. I sent him a couple of picture and in return he gave me the following pictures with instructions. I am in no way trying to promote this service, but the instructions provided solved my issue.

[image]

[image]